# Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (8:12)

Tags: jsx

Module build failed (from ../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\sriha\mastersproject\masters-projects\mono-repo\packages\components\textField\textField.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (8:12):

6 |
7 |     // },[])

> 8 |     return(
> |            ^
> 9 |     {props.name}
> 10 |     <input type="text" id={props.id}name={props.name} value={inputValue} onChange={(e)=>{setValue(e.target.value)}}/>
> 11 |

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.